# Proof of coherent state displacement operator solution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, coherent-states

In $3D$ space I have two $2\times2$ non-Hermitian matrix operators, $A$ and $A^\dagger$, of the form:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11}(x_j,\partial_j) & A_{12}(x_j,\partial_j)\\
A_{21}(x_j,\partial_j) & A_{22}(x_j,\partial_j)
\end{pmatrix}$$
That is, each component is a differential operator. These operators act on the states of the form:
$$\psi(x_j)=\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_\uparrow(x_j)\\
\psi_\downarrow(x_j)
\end{pmatrix}$$

The displacement operator for the coherent states of these states is defined as:
$$D(\alpha)=\exp(\alpha A^\dagger-\alpha^* A)$$

For $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$. A coherent state can be defined as:
$$\psi_\alpha=D(\alpha)\psi_0=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\left(\alpha A^\dagger-\alpha^* A\right)^n\psi_0$$

Through an educated guess using the symmetries of the system, I found the form of the state $\psi_\alpha$ for a specific $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, which I numerically confirmed after an expansion of over a dozen terms to an accuracy of over $99\%$.

Thus I have:
$$\psi_\text{sol.}=D(\alpha)\psi_0$$
$$\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
\psi_{\text{sol.},\uparrow}(x_j)\\ 
\psi_{\text{sol.},\downarrow}(x_j)
\end{pmatrix}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\alpha^n}{n!}\left[\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11}(x_j,\partial_j)^\dagger & A_{21}(x_j,\partial_j)^\dagger\\
A_{12}(x_j,\partial_j)^\dagger & A_{22}(x_j,\partial_j)^\dagger
\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11}(x_j,\partial_j) & A_{12}(x_j,\partial_j)\\
A_{21}(x_j,\partial_j) & A_{22}(x_j,\partial_j)
\end{pmatrix}\right]^n\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_{0,\uparrow}(x_j)\\
\psi_{0,\downarrow}(x_j)
\end{pmatrix}$$

Where I know the starting state, $\psi_0$, the coherent state, $\psi_\text{sol.}$, the form of the differential operators, $A_{ij}$ and $A_{ij}^\dagger$, and the real number $\alpha$. I have confirmed this identity numerically, how can I prove it analytically? I can't see a way to start since the operators constantly couple the spin-up and down states together.

Comment: Are your operators bosonic? Do they always satisfy $AA^\dagger-A^\dagger A=\mathbb{I}$?

Comment: @QuantumMechanic no, they satisfy neither $AA^\dagger-A^\dagger A=\mathbb{I}$ nor $AA^\dagger+A^\dagger A=\mathbb{I}$ in general.

Comment: Hm. Then I don't see why this should be the displacement operator per se. Is there any closure relation for $D(\alpha) D(\beta)$?

Comment: @QuantumMechanic There is no closure relation that I can prove (i.e., anything of the form $D(\alpha)D(\beta)=D(\alpha\beta)$). There is a slightly modified version of these operators that are operators corresponding to the root vectors of an $SO(3,2)$ symmetry. These vectors are scalar multiples of $A$ and $A^\dagger$ similar to the scaling of the RL vector in the hydrogen atom (which includes the principle quantum number). They may satisfy the relation. I use the term "displacement operator" as I'm trying to find the "magnetic translation operators" of a system in 3D with a new gauge.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic and when I say "They may satisfy the relation", I don't believe the state I've defined on the LHS of $\psi_\text{sol}=D(\alpha)\psi_0$ remains the solution if $A\rightarrow\tilde{A}$ (where $\tilde{A}$ is the scaled version that depends on one of the quantum numbers)

Comment: What is the question actually?

Comment: @MengCheng The question is: how do I actually prove that the RHS equals the LHS of the last equation? I guessed the correct form (the LHS) but don't know how to prove it analytically.

Comment: So far $\psi_{sol}$ is defined as $D(\alpha)\psi_0$. There is nothing to prove...

Comment: @MengCheng I mean if I have the $\left(\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{n!}}(-\mathbf {x} \cdot \mathbf {\nabla } )^{n}\right)\psi (\mathbf {r} )$ then I can guess that this is equal to $\psi (\mathbf {r} -\mathbf {x} )$. However, this is just a guess (even if it is correct) until I prove the two are equal. So I have the operators repeatedly acting on the RHS and a closed form with no operators on the LHS that I found through an educated guess. How can I prove that the infinite sum of operators acting on the state can be written in the closed form that I call $\psi_\text{sol}$?

Comment: @QPhysl Your $D(\alpha)$ is defined as the infinite sum. If there is no independent definition of $\psi_{\rm sol}$ (like it solves a certain equation), then there is nothing to prove.

Comment: @MengCheng I have the exact form of $\psi_\text{sol}$. Specifically, it is of the form: $e^{-|\mathbf{r}-\delta z\mathbf{\hat{z}}/4|}e^{im\phi}[J_m(\delta z \rho/2)|\uparrow>+J_{m+a}(\delta z \rho/2)e^{i\phi}|\downarrow>]$ where $\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $r$ and $\phi$ are the usual polar coordinates and $\delta z\in\mathbb{R}$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. I also know the operators and need to show that the infinite sum acting on a spin-up Gaussian gives this state. Are you saying that this is impossible to prove?

Comment: @QPhysl I don't know whether it's possible to prove it, but you did not include this form of $\psi_{\rm sol}$ in the question, then it's impossible for anyone to give meaningful answers. I suggest you update your question so it's clear what to prove.